# CMake cannot compile test program as source directory doesnt exist

Tags: cmake

all. I'm trying to use cmake for compile some android code with android toolchain on Windows 7x64.

when i call cmake as following
`cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=android.cmake 1>!cmake.log      2>!cmake.error.log`

I run this command from Administrator console and get following output:

`!cmake.log`

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.6.0
-- Check for working C compiler: c:/cygwin/usr/local/android-toolchain-r8ea9/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: c:/cygwin/usr/local/android-toolchain-r8ea9/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe -- broken
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

`!cmake.error.log`

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
The C compiler
  "c:/cygwin/usr/local/android-toolchain-r8ea9/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/PDK_BUILD/openssl/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:C:/PROGRA~2/CMAKE2~1.8/bin/cmake.exe
  "cmTryCompileExec333575975/fast"

  CMake Error: The source directory
  "C:/PDK_BUILD/openssl/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTryCompileExec333575975/fast"
  does not exist.


  Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.






  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
```

I granted adninistrator rights for cmake.exe itself, cleared read-only attributes from `CMakeFiles` folder and disabled anti-virus but still not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are running into [CMake Bug 0013131](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13131). [This comment suggests](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13131#c29436) that using `unset TMP` should fix the problem. Don't forget to delete the `CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeFiles` folders (or the entire build tree when using out-of-source builds), before retrying.