# Simple test output - CMake Error: The source directory does not exist

Tags: cmake, clion

When I create new project in Clion, cmake cannot find CMakeTmp directory.

**Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/cmake cmTC_df723/fast && No such file or directory**

OS: Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu based)

I have tried:

- reinstalling gcc (now on version 8.3.0)
- reinstalling cmake (now on version 3.15.2)
- unset TMP from ([CMake cannot compile test program as source directory doesnt exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275822/cmake-cannot-compile-test-program-as-source-directory-doesnt-exist))
- set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
- set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
- checked permissions to ClionProject subdirectories

Error output:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/sacha/CLionProjects/testProject
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: /usr/bin/cmake cmTC_df723/fast && 
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

   "/usr/bin/gcc"

 is not able to compile a simple test program.

 It fails with the following output:

 Change Dir: /home/sacha/CLionProjects/testProject/cmake-build-release-system/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

 Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/cmake cmTC_df723/fast && No such file or directory
Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: /usr/bin/cmake cmTC_df723/fast &&
```

Any help or directions appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The first error message you got is `CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed.`, I would interpret it as "something wrong with your environment settings". In the argument `-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr"/bin/cmake` which sets `make` command the double quote looks very suspicious. It could be the very reason which invalidates the path to `make`.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, when editing readable output. My cmake settings have correct **-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/cmake** without quotation mark. I already edited the question error output, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: There is more serious problem with `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` parameter: it should refer to **Make** executable, but `/usr/bin/cmake`, according to its last component, refers to **CMake** one. These executables are definitely not interchangeable. Probably, you need `/usr/bin/make` instead (or just type `which make` and find the proper path).

Comment: You are right! Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

```
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed.
```

signals, that something **wrong with CMake settings** or its [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

---

In the given case you have additional message

```
Make command was: /usr/bin/cmake cmTC_df723/fast &&
```

which means that `cmake` is run as a Make command.

This is wrong: `cmake` and `make` commands are not interchangeable.

Would you inspect the very first command line, you will find the source of that problem:

```
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/cmake
```

Exactly it sets `cmake` executable for Make command. You need to fix that line (e.g. in CLion settings).